# Is it possible to authenticate to GitHub using OpenID?

Tags: github, openid

I just want to report a bug to a GitHub project, and I'd hate to go through opening yet another account just for that. OpenID authentication would have been perfect for me - but unfortunately, I cannot see that GitHub supports it.

So can anyone post explicitly, if one can authenticate to GitHub using OpenID or not? Has it ever been possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github's never had openID authentication, so your only option is to create an account.